# Access constant members of one class inside another class member

Tags: php, class, static, constants

I have the following classes:

```
class Mode{
    const Enabled = 1;
    const Disabled = 2;
    const Pending = 3;
}
class Product{
    public static $Modes = Mode;
}
```

I want to access constants of class Mode from statically access on Product.

```
if($product_mode == Product::$Modes::Pending){
    //do something
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you expand on your use case? It sounds to me as if you are going about something the wrong way.

Comment: I'm using autoload to automatically load my classes, so if I put Mode class inside of Product.php, it will be automatically loaded only when Product is used. When I call Mode::Pending directly, without use Product, error occurs telling that Mode class doesn't exists.

Comment: Are `Mode` and `Product` declared in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:-

```
if($product_mode == Mode::Pending){
    //do something
}
```

within the Product class, although I doubt its the best way of achieving whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way:

```
class Base{
    static public function getC($const)
    {
        $const = explode('/', $const);
        if(count($const)!=2)
            return;
        $cls = new ReflectionClass($const[0]);
        $consts = $cls->getConstants();
        return $consts[$const[1]];
    }
}
class Mode{
    const Enabled = 1;
    const Disabled = 2;
    const Pending = 3;

}
class Product extends Base{

}

echo Product::getC('Mode/Pending');
```